# Why is my BubbleSearch only partially working?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I created this method to Bubble Search an array
and it's returning a 'slightly' ordered array.

for example, when I enter: 
4
2
9
11
12
5

It returns:
2
4
9
5
11
12

```
    public static void bubbleSort(int array[]){


        boolean fixed= false;

        while(fixed==false){

            for(int i=0; i<array.length-1; i++){
                int temp;
                fixed=true;

                if (array[i] > array[i+1]){
                    temp= array[i+1];
                    array[i+1]= array[i];

                    array[i]= temp;
                    fixed=false;
                    }
            }
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Move `fixed=true` before the for loop

```
public static void bubbleSort(int array[]){
    boolean fixed = false;
    while(!fixed){
        fixed = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length-1; ++i){
            int temp;
            if (array[i] > array[i+1]){
                temp = array[i+1];
                array[i+1] = array[i];

                array[i] = temp;
                fixed = false;
            }   
        }   
    }    
}
```

Comment: This was the problem, thank you very much!

Also, I meant Bubble Sort* lol

Answer (score 2):

Ryan, I think if you move fixed = true; outside the for loop, it might resolve the issue. I have not tested this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify your code a little.To move the fixed = true statement out of your for loop.This fixed flag is used to indicated if there is any swap happen in your for loop.Your problem occur because the 5 less than 11, and a swap happen,change fixed to false but next iteration override the fixed to true.And the for loop end, the while check fixed, found it is true, and program stop.